# Next 13 | Custom not found don't overwrite metadata title

Tags: next.js, metadata, next.js13

When you try to make a custom page "not-found.tsx" and try to export a metadata:
`"export const metadata: {title: 'Page not found!' }"`

You can't overwrite the curent metadata!!!

Better explaining, i'm currently working on a websystem using [nextjs13](/questions/tagged/nextjs13).
When the user is not logged in, the page that they are trying access will return the not found.
`if (!user) { return notFound() };`

So, they will need to login to access that page, but to protect this route, i need to return a not found page.
The real problem is: the page that the user are trying to access have a current metadata, and the not found don't overwrite.

It's a bug of the version or anything, or i'm doing something wrong?!

I'm trying to fix that, but i have no idea how i can deal with it!
I just thinked about using **generateMetadata** instead of the default **metadata**;